# Joining based on a condition in Teradata

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements, teradata, where-clause

I am trying to write something like the below:

```
case when table_1.account_or_client='A' then inner join on table_1.addr_id=table_2.addr_id where substr(table_2.addr_id,2,1) is not 0
else then inner join on table_1.addr_id=table_2.addr_id
```

but in proper syntax. How do I do this?

I need to make sure that the second digit of table_2.addr_id is not 0 during the join when table_1.account_or_client='A'

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Obviously your code snippet is not proper SQL and can easily be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

*I need to make sure that the second digit of table_2.addr_id is not 0 during the join when table_1.account_or_client='A'* translates to

```
FROM table_1 AS t1 
JOIN table_2 AS t2
  ON t1.addr_id=t2.addr_id
 AND NOT (t1.account_or_client='A' AND Substr(t2.addr_id,2,1) = '0')
```